# Get unique parents from specific records (ancestry)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ancestry

Is there a way to get unique parents of specific records? This is the way I do it now, but it slows the website down a lot:

```
roots = []
categories_with_products.each {|cat| roots << cat.root.id}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
categories_with_products.pluck(:root_id).uniq
```

Comment: It says PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "root_id" does not exist. Root_id seems to be only virtual attribute of ancestry, not the Model itself. Am I missing anything?

Comment: What about: `categories_with_products.map{|cat| cat.root.id}.uniq`

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an array, you can do it using [uniq](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/uniq) method:

```
categories_with_products.uniq{ |x| x.root_id }
```

However, if you want to get it directly from database, you can use the [distinct](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/distinct) method:

```
Model.distinct.pluck(:root_id)
```

I hope it helps!